# How do I write a terraform code to create an aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm for too many db connections?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

In AWS CloudWatch I can create an alarm that will alert me if my database has too many connections:

[image]

And I have used terraform to create another alarm ...

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "cpu_utilization_too_high" {
  alarm_name          = "cpu_utilization_too_high"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "CPUUtilization"
  namespace           = "AWS/RDS"
  period              = "600"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = var.cpu_utilization_threshold
  alarm_description   = "Average database CPU utilization over last 10 minutes too high"
  alarm_actions       = [aws_sns_topic.topic.arn]
  ok_actions          = [aws_sns_topic.topic.arn]

  dimensions = {
    DBInstanceIdentifier = "${var.db_instance_id}"
  }
}
```

Now I want to use terraform to create an alarm that will alert me to my database connections but I do not know what to set `metric_name` to ...

```
  metric_name         = ???TooMuchConnectingtoDataBase???
```

I have looked at the terraform documentation but it doesn't document what do use for the metric_name. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MonitoringOverview.html#monitoring-cloudwatch),

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "too_many_db_connections" {
  alarm_name          = "too_many_db_connections"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "DatabaseConnections"
  namespace           = "AWS/RDS"
  period              = "600"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = var.db_connection_threshold
  alarm_description   = "Average db connections over last 10 minutes is too high"
  alarm_actions       = [aws_sns_topic.topic.arn]
  ok_actions          = [aws_sns_topic.topic.arn]

  dimensions = {
    DBInstanceIdentifier = "${var.db_instance_id}"
  }
}
```